# How to deploy Mule Application on Kubernetes?

Tags: docker, mule, kubernetes, minikube

We are trying to deploy Mule Application on Kubernetes using Minikube. Could you please explain the steps to deploy on Kubernetes in windows environment.

Comment: What do you mean here under "Windows environment"? Do you use minikube (it's Linux-based) on Windows or you'd like to deploy Mule Application in Windows-based Kubernetes environment (https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/windows/)?

Comment: We are using minikube on windows machine.We have used VirtualBox.As far as we know for standalone deployment we requires minikube for kubernetes.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you would need to install Minikube for Windows: https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/releases

Then, install the API client `kubectl`: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/

Then, according to the needs to your application, you will have to create different API Objects, most likely:

- Deployment (also, you may have to create a container): https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/
- Service: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/
- Persistent Volumes (in case you need persistence): https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/

This will need some knowledge of how k8s works so I advise you to check the Kubernetes documentation (https://kubernetes.io/docs) and some get started guides.

Answer (score 0):

You need `kubectl` and `minikube` in Windows for `Kubernetes`.
Once you able to start your `minikube` on your system, you can deploy Mule application in `Kubernate` directly through the dashboard or using `kubectl` interface.
It will pull the mule docker image from the DockerHub into your Kubernetes container.
Here is how you can do it by both the ways and deploy Mule application:
http://anirban-blog.logdown.com/posts/2505689-kubernetes-and-minikube
http://anirban-blog.logdown.com/posts/2550426-kubernetes-and-minikube-part2
and
http://bushorn.com/mule-on-kubernetes/